# Receiving TypeError: codecs_data_structures_1.getBytesCodec is not a function while importing @solana/spl-token

Tags: solanaspl-token

I'm integrating Wormhole and Solana into my react web application, but in the execution phase I receive the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , codecs_data_structures_1.getBytesCodec) is not a function
```

[image]

I tried the following solutions:

- Update the library to the latest version
- Add babel-loader to compile this specific library

This is my config-overrides.js file:

```
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.m?js/,
    resolve: {
      fullySpecified: false
    }
  })

  config.resolve.fallback = {
    url: require.resolve('url'),
    assert: require.resolve('assert'),
    crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
    http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
    https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
    process: require.resolve('process'),
    history: require.resolve('history'),
    os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
    buffer: require.resolve('buffer'),
    stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
    fs: false,
    path: false,
    child_process: false,
    "readable-stream": false
  };

  config.plugins.push(
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      process: 'process/browser',
      Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
    }),
  );

  config.experiments = {
    asyncWebAssembly: true,
  }

  config.ignoreWarnings = [/Failed to parse source map/]

  return config;
}
```

I'm using react-scripts (v5.0.1) as a react framework, react v18.2 and react-app-rewired v2.2.1